# How to transform a matplotlib chart to a sole interactive file

Tags: flash, svg, matplotlib, interactive

I am developing an application of financial report analysis basically to crunch numbers and plot bar/line/pie/scatter .. charts accordingly. The application is based on Pandas and matplotlib and works well. The end users just send me the parameters, and the application will run and generate the chart files in SVG format , then I can email the files to the end-users.

Now the problem is:  the SVG file is static and lose the interactive ability, end users want the chart to show related annotation when mouse click or hover over the key points or areas.

I have add interactive function for matplotlib charts on my machine, but it relys on my installed environment. The end-users run on Windows and will not install python/matplotlib etc., what they want is just a single file that they can double-click and then interactive with the content.

what I want now is : the easiest way to transform matplotlib charts to that kind of file. somewhat like transform the pic to flash or dynamic SVG or whatever file that users can interacive with.

Is there any python existing package or any thought for this ? Thanks,

Comment: maybe wrap up the data, your code, pandas and matplotilb with py2exe ? (not sure if that is even possible though)

Comment: @wvxvw: Why rely on Flash and ActionScript? You can do the same thing using plain SVG and JavaScript. Or is there a killer feature of Flash that seems relevant for animating a chart?

Comment: @wvxvw: I would package the JavaScript inside the SVG file. I don't see where the OP required an executable Windows program. I think with SVG he'd be far more flexible.

Comment: I'd expect that the client's machine has a decent browser installed, so no need to package anything. The current solution obviously is to send him SVG anyway, so he *can* view it (presumably in a browser). He would receive SVG like before, but this time with interactivity.

Comment: @bigbug: It would be useful to know what interactive features you want exactly (just displaying some info popup when clicking on a bar of a chart is something totally different than, say, dynamically redimensioning bars/pies). Maybe you could also clarify the topic of our little discussion concerning Flash vs. SVG.

Comment: thanks all for your information. I prefer the SVG+javascript solution. The end users have browser installed (most of the end users OS are windows XP and browser are IE, so i also need to persuade them to install Chrome or Firefox),a single SVG with JavaScript embedded sounds OK. As the interactive feature, the current urgent requirement is just displaying some information popup when mouse hover over or click on a line/bar/bubble.., no animation, no dynamic redimensioning, no zoom in/out. (they might raise this requirement later on, who knows). So I am looking forwarded the quickest way.

Comment: I am open to flash or SVG solution. Both JavaScript and Actionscript are new for me and the requirement is urgent, so the little to learn, the better. (I am dreaming of matplotlib develop guys can directly add an option to its plot command, then it can directly generate interactive SVG/flash)

Comment: A quick and easy solution could be to show the popup information using the `<title>` element (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=matplotlib+interactive+svg) finds an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994357/want-to-make-static-svg-plot-from-matplotlib-interactive-via-the-browser/10542968#10542968) to this which points to an [example on matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/svg_histogram.html). Assuming that the user will open this file in a web browser, this should work. If he opens it with Inkscape or a static SVG viewer, then there's no way to give him an interactive experience. You could of course also upload the chart and send him a link. This would probably be most convenient and make sure he views it in a browser.

Alternatively, consider using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) instead of matplotlib. It uses JavaScript generated SVG and has amazing charting features. It might be easier to add the desired interactive behavior to those.

A quick solution for displaying information when the mouse hovers above some element is using the `<title>` element in SVG. The content of any `<title>` element will be displayed as a tootlip on hover. See [this example](http://tinkerbin.com/LkHSyW9j):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="150">
  <rect width="50" height="50">
    <title>This is a rectangle</title>
  </rect>
  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="25">
    <title>This is a circle</title>
  </circle>
  <text y="120">
    <tspan>Move your mouse over the</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="20">elements to see the title text.</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, building a website and host the application in the cloud is the long term solution. d3 is awesome. But I am an amateurish programmer and a lot of efforts are already put on matplotlib, totally using d3 to replace matplotlib sounds not a solution for me in short time. (any python wrapper for d3, or translator from matplotlib to d3)? The "answer" link is helpful, I will have a try.